# Make listboxitem unselectable

Tags: wpf, listbox

I'm writing an small key application and I'm using a listbox to dynamically visualise a list from code. Now the issue is it needs to be used on windows 7 and I'm having multiple issues with the visualisation on that platform.

The code I have is:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxSecrets" Margin="0,84,10,10" Background="{x:Null}"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!--<Border BorderBrush="#FFF3560D" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,0,10">-->
        <Border BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="10" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="30" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Uid="{Binding Path=ID}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    ...
                </StackPanel>


                <Button  ... Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                    ...
                </Button>
                <Button  ... Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="3" >
                    ...
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I tried the following style to no effect:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is how the selection looks - I don't want it to be selectable. (I have the same issue with the buttons btw - same solution would be applicable?)

Before: 
[image]

After click:
[image]

Also: Bonus points if you can help me figure out how to remove the "aliasing" line between the grid and the border around it.. ;-; Only happens on the win 7 mahcine, not my win 8 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the selection upon happening? Like this:

```
private void listBoxSecrets_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxSecrets.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

You then setup the listener like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxSecrets" Margin="0,84,10,10" Background="{x:Null}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="listBoxSecrets_SelectionChanged" >
```

Comment: How would I add this function to the listbox click event? since I'm creating the listboxes through a DataTemplate

Comment: After some debugigng I found that the glitch I'm getting is actually due to the border being selected! how would I fix that?

Comment: Ooh I get it now it's not selected it's got focus! Try `listBoxSecrets.Focus();`. Add this line after `listBoxSecrets.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to remove the selection state of ListBoxItem, if thats right, Please use the below style,
in this i have commented out the triggers responsible for selection and mouse over state.
You can assign this style in ItemContainerStyle of ListBox,,

```
  <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--<MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>-->
                        <!--<MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>-->
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: After some debugigng I found that the glitch I'm getting is actually due to the border being selected! how would I fix that?

Comment: with the above style?

Comment: what kind of issues? if you share your style, we can look into that.

Comment: Well the only style I had was the one you pasted above (or the one from the original post)  But I've fixed the issue now! Discovering that it was the border that gav eme issues was enough. I added the property  ' Focusable="False" ' and that fixed it!